# Write cross-table queries with QueryDSL and Spring's Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, querydsl

I've build a DAL which uses Spring's Repositories to manage CRUD operations on a MySQL DB through Hibernate and JPA. In particular this is my Repository definition

```
package my.dal.repository;

import my.domain.dal.User;

import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User>{

}
```

With this definition I'm able to execute CRUD operations using QueryDSL Predicates 
through the extension of the `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` interface and the `findAll(Predicate)` method.

The problem I'm facing is that this way I'm not able to make cross-table queries. Indeed, I cannot use QueryDSL's join facilities because I don't have a `HibernateQuery`.

What is the right way to implement the join operation with Spring Repositories and QueryDSL?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

Below I write the steps needed to execute a QueryDSL query with Spring Repositories

1. Acquire the `EntityManager` used in the application context by adding the `EntityManager` attribute in the `Service` class with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation

   ```
   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager em;
   ```

   This way the em attribute will link to the `EntityManager` bean
   defined in the Spring application context.
2. Instantiate a [JPAQuery](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/1.9.6/apidocs/com/mysema/query/hql/jpa/JPAQuery.html) object and use it

   ```
   QUser qUser = QUser.user;
   JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
   User charlie = query
       .from(qUser)
       .where(qUser.username.eq("charlie"))
       .uniqueResult(qUser);
   ```

Now we can use the `JPQLQuery` object to execute joins over different tables.

Hope this helps