# How to get the details of farmer in spring boot using the UserServiceImpl?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, backend

How to view details of farmer through the userServiceImpl class? We cant use the farmerServiceImpl as we have to pass the username as the input not the id and username is not present in farmerClass.

User class:

```
public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        @NotBlank(message = "Username is mandatory")
        @Size(max = 20)
        private String username;
        @NotBlank(message = "Password is mandatory")
        @Size(max = 50)
        private String password;
        
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
        @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
        private Set<Role> roles;
        
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade =  {CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.PERSIST},
                mappedBy = "user")
        @JsonIgnore
        private Farmer farmer;
    }
```

Farmer Class:

```
public class Farmer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int farmerId;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String name;    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String address;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 12)
    private String phoneNo;

    // OneToOne unidirectional relationship 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;
    

}
```

UserServiceImpl :

```
public User viewUser(String username) {
        <<<How to viewdetails of farmer class through this method>>>
    }
```

Comment: You don't. Write a proper query that returns what you want. And that method should be on the farmerservice (and properly the `FarmerRepository` for the qyery.

Comment: How can i pass the input variable "username" through the query as we dont have "username" field in farmer class?

Comment: You have a link to `User` in your `Farmer` so you can write it for that. Something like `SELECT f FROM Farmer f WHERE f.user.username=:username`... I strongly suggest learning JPA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write cross-table queries with QueryDSL and Spring's Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139668/write-cross-table-queries-with-querydsl-and-springs-repository)